# How to select an element by title with JavaScript and update it

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, jquery-selectors

How do you select and modify an element by it's title?

```
javascript: (function () {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<style>* {
    background:% 20#000 % 20!important;
    color:% 20#0f0 % 20!important;
    outline:% 20solid % 20#f00 % 201px % 20!important;
  } </style > `;
})();
```

I need to update the snippet / bookmarklet so when I run it (I have it on my bookmarks bar) it changes the position of a certain element in the document.

The only way I could select this element is by its `title` attribute.

Comment: so - what code have you tried, to select the item by title?

Comment: Note: selecting something by name (rather than id) can work a little like this: `"div[name=abcd]"`, so title might work that way too...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[**CSS Selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

Use the selector notation for finding a node by it's attribute

```css
[title="element title attribute value"]
```

---

Using ***JavaScript***

Same selector as in CSS, but you can get the *Node* using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), or if expecting multiple *Nodes*, a *NodeList* via [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)

```js
var node = document.querySelector('[title="element title attribute value"]');
```

---

When you do `.innerHTML`, you are causing a re-parse of all *HTML* in the node you've called it on and this can literally destroy sections of web pages. You should use *DOM methods* for creating nodes, instead. e.g.

```js
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode('div {border: 1px solid red}'));
document.body.appendChild(style);
```

---

Converting *JavaScript* into a bookmarklet is as simple as

```
bookmarklet = 'javascript:'
    + encodeURIComponent('(function () {' + code + '}())')
    + ';';
```

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6mrrz5h/) where you can just paste in code

Comment: It only gets the first element with that title. How do I get all of them?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Use "querySelectorAll" instead of "querySelector"