# Using Puppeteer to find element by title

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Assuming I have a link in an iframe without an id, where the only uniquely identifiable piece of information is the element title of this link, how would I go about finding it? It could look like this:

```
<a class="link spacer--double" href="#" tabindex="51" title="Click here to use new code">Use new code</a>
```

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
(async() => {    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();    
    console.log("starting new page");
    var contentHtml = fs.readFileSync('1-iframe.html', 'utf8');
    await page.setContent(contentHtml);

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let elements = document.getElementById("framecontentscroll").innerText;
        for (let element of elements)
            console.log(element);
    })    
    })();
```

But I don't seem to get anything in `elements`. The id of the iframe is "framecontentscroll".

Is there a way where I can go directly for the link element using it's title and a `querySelector` or something similar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select an element by title with JavaScript and tweak from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277125/select-an-element-by-title-with-javascript-and-tweak-from-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `querySelector` to select by title. See:

[Select an element by title with JavaScript and tweak from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277125/select-an-element-by-title-with-javascript-and-tweak-from-the-browser#answer-25277157)

Comment: You should flag as duplicate instead of answering with a single sentence and a link.