# Select multiple items by title with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying so select multiple items using `document.querySelectorAll` and getting the elements by their html `title`.

I also need to insert multiple selectors in my query: i have a vector with `n` elements, and each one is a `title` that i need to select.

I already followed this answer: [Select an element by title with JavaScript and modify it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277125/select-an-element-by-title-with-javascript-and-modify-it) but without any success.

I managed to make it work, but only for a single element.

1) `Html`

```
<div id="pad">
    <ol class="even first">
        <li class='hex' title="C2">
            <div class="note">C2</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="G2">
            <div class="note">G2</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="D3">
            <div class="note">D3</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="A3">
            <div class="note">A3</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="E4">
            <div class="note">E4</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="odd">
        <li class='hex' title="A1">
            <div class="note">A1</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="E2">
            <div class="note">E2</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="B2">
            <div class="note">B2</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="Gb3">
            <div class="note">Gb3</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="Db4">
            <div class="note">Db4</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="Ab4">
            <div class="note">Ab4</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="even">
        <li class='hex' title="Db2">
            <div class="note">Db2</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="Ab2">
            <div class="note">Ab2</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="Eb3">
            <div class="note">Eb3</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="Bb3">
            <div class="note">Bb3</div>
        </li>
        <li class='hex' title="F4">
            <div class="note">F4</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

This is the html of an hexagonal music keyboard.

2)  `javascript`

```
notes = ['C2','E2','G2']
keys = document.querySelectorAll(".hex"); //this works fine
//correctly select the single node with title = 'C2'
selected_notes = document.querySelectorAll('[title="C2"]');
```

How do i "insert" my array in the query in order to select all the elements with title C2, E2 or G2?

I would like to do something like this:

```
selected_notes = document.querySelectorAll('[title=notes]'); //obviously this doesn't work
```

Is it possible to do it? Or i have to iterate a single query over each element of my `notes` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `querySelectorAll` alone, unfortunately, you'll have to write out each possible title attribute, and put it into the query string:

```js
const selected_notes = document.querySelectorAll('[title="C2"], [title="E2"], [title="G2"]');
console.log(selected_notes);
```

```html
<div id="pad">
  <ol class="even first">
    <li class='hex' title="C2"><div class="note">C2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="G2"><div class="note">G2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="D3"><div class="note">D3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="A3"><div class="note">A3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="E4"><div class="note">E4</div></li>
  </ol>  
  <ol class="odd">
    <li class='hex' title="A1"><div class="note">A1</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="E2"><div class="note">E2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="B2"><div class="note">B2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Gb3"><div class="note">Gb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Db4"><div class="note">Db4</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Ab4"><div class="note">Ab4</div></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="even">
    <li class='hex' title="Db2"><div class="note">Db2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Ab2"><div class="note">Ab2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Eb3"><div class="note">Eb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Bb3"><div class="note">Bb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="F4"><div class="note">F4</div></li>
  </ol>
```

To make things more DRY, I'd `.map` an array of the titles you want to the elements:

```js
const notes = ['C2','E2','G2'];
const selected_notes = notes.map(title => document.querySelector(`[title="${title}"]`));
console.log(selected_notes);
```

```html
<div id="pad">
  <ol class="even first">
    <li class='hex' title="C2"><div class="note">C2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="G2"><div class="note">G2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="D3"><div class="note">D3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="A3"><div class="note">A3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="E4"><div class="note">E4</div></li>
  </ol>  
  <ol class="odd">
    <li class='hex' title="A1"><div class="note">A1</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="E2"><div class="note">E2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="B2"><div class="note">B2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Gb3"><div class="note">Gb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Db4"><div class="note">Db4</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Ab4"><div class="note">Ab4</div></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="even">
    <li class='hex' title="Db2"><div class="note">Db2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Ab2"><div class="note">Ab2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Eb3"><div class="note">Eb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Bb3"><div class="note">Bb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="F4"><div class="note">F4</div></li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this even with classes? I didn't understand the sintax: `[title="${title}"]` . Can i change it to get classes instead of title? I tried to replace title with class (which seemed reasonable to me) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think i solved the problem, using this `var selected_notes = notes.map(title => document.querySelectorAll("."+title));` works for elements inside the class field.

Comment: `${expression}` syntax is string interpolation inside template literals. It's like `'foo' + someVarName + 'bar'` which is ordinary concatenation

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve that is to [group selectors into one rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Groups_of_selectors_on_one_rule), be separating distinct selectors for each targeted value of the `"title"` attribute like this:

```
[title="C2"], [title="E2"], [title="G2"]
```

The selector above would achieve the following result (selection visualised with pink background applied to selected nodes):

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[title="C2"], [title="E2"], [title="G2"]');

for(const node of nodes) {
  node.style.background = "pink";
}
```

```html
<div id="pad">
  <ol class="even first">
    <li class='hex' title="C2"><div class="note">C2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="G2"><div class="note">G2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="D3"><div class="note">D3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="A3"><div class="note">A3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="E4"><div class="note">E4</div></li>
  </ol>  
  <ol class="odd">
    <li class='hex' title="A1"><div class="note">A1</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="E2"><div class="note">E2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="B2"><div class="note">B2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Gb3"><div class="note">Gb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Db4"><div class="note">Db4</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Ab4"><div class="note">Ab4</div></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="even">
    <li class='hex' title="Db2"><div class="note">Db2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Ab2"><div class="note">Ab2</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Eb3"><div class="note">Eb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="Bb3"><div class="note">Bb3</div></li>
    <li class='hex' title="F4"><div class="note">F4</div></li>
  </ol>
```